# How do I create multiple shapes with Fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I want to be able to create multiple rectangles on the canvas using double clicks. However, I'm able to create only one rectangle. Also, is there is a way to add an ID to every rectangle that is created? I want to be able to access any rectangle I want at any time and change its properties.

```
var i=0;

function drawRectangle() {
   if (rectClickToggle) {
          getMouse(event);
          var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('drawArea');
          canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({width:20,height:20,fill:'#f55',top:my,left:mx}));
          canvas.item(i).set({borderColor:'red',cornerColor:'green',cornerSize:6,transparentCorners: false});
          canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.item(i));   
          i++;
       }
  }

 drawArea.ondblclick = drawRectangle;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call the drawRectangle function you are redefining the canvas.  Try moving that code outside the drawRectangle function.

---

**Edit** - for drawing many rectangles.

```
var canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas('canvas-ele');
canvas.setHeight(300);
canvas.setWidth(300);
var drawRect = function(e) {
    canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
            left: e.x - 10,
            top: e.y - 10,
            fill: 'rgba(100,0,0,0.3)',
            width: 72,
            height: 72,
            stroke: 'black'
        })
    );
};
var canvasEle = document.getElementById('canvas-ele');
canvasEle.ondblclick = function (e) {
    drawRect(e);
};
canvas.renderAll();
```

Try the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/coryasilva/Y5fu5/

***As a side note I do not recommend using a double click; it makes for a poor user experience)

---

**Edit #2**

I understand better now.  How does this work?

http://jsfiddle.net/Y5fu5/3/

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work. The rectangle won't render. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I need a dynamic canvas - one on which I can resize and move shapes. Thus, double click is kind of like my default option here. However, the fabric library does not seem to have a double click event listener. Any suggestions? I tried modifying your code to make the canvas dynamic but it does not track the coordinates of the mouse click if I do that.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much. May I ask why you subtract 10 from the mouse coordinates?

Comment: I just subtracted 10 to visually compensate for the default windows mouse pointer.  If you set the cursor to crosshairs you will want to remove the subtraction of 10 form x and y.